# Why does multiplying a vector by $A^{-1}$ give the same result as reducing $A$ to RREF?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given the linear operator  $T$ in $ℝ^2$ where

$$T:(x,y)↦(s,t)$$

defined by the equations

$$2x+y=s$$

$$6x+2y=t$$

Determine the image of the line $x+y=1$ under the given operator.

---

My question is why does method 1 give the same answer as method 2.

**Method 1 (textbook answer):**

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}2&1\\6&2\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\6&2\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}s\\t\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=$ $A^{-1}$ $\begin{bmatrix}s\\t\end{bmatrix}$

Using Cramer's rule gives

$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-s+\frac{1}{2}t\\3s-t\end{bmatrix}$

Thus the image of $x+y=1$ is $2s-\frac{1}{2}t=1$

**Method 2 (The method I used):**

Form the augmented matrix where column 1 represents x and column 2 represents y,

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}2&1&s\\6&2&t\end{bmatrix}$

Reducing to REF gives (or RREF for lefthand side of matrix)

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-s+\frac{1}{2}t\\0&1&3s-t\end{bmatrix}$
Now see that $x=-s+\frac{1}{2}t$ and $y=3s-t$

Thus the image of $x+y=1$ is $2s-\frac{1}{2}t=1$

---

**My question:**  Why does method 1 give the same answer as method 2?

Method 2 kind of looks like the inversion algorithm
$$[A|I]$$
where reducing $A$ to $I$ undos $A$  and produces $A^{-1}$ on the right side, giving
$$[I|A^{-1}]$$

The problem with this is that the matrix in method 2

$$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&|s\\6&2&|t\end{bmatrix}$$

does not have the identity matrix on the righthand side of the matrix, so it does not have the form $[A|I]$

Comment: How about $I$ times the vector $[s, t]^{\top}$?

Comment: That would work but I'm not sure if the righthand side has to originally be given as $I$ because the right side would have to be $I$ so that $A^-1$ becomes the right side, in this case the right side is a vector rather than identity matrix

Comment: By attaching the vector $[x, y]^{\top}$ on the left side and $I$ times $[s, t]^{\top}$ on the right side, you basically have a short-hand version of $\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\6&2\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}s\\t\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Does method 2 work because $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=A^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}s\\t\end{bmatrix}$  represents the inversion algorithm of the form $[A|I[s,t]^{T}]$ since the question asks to compute $A^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}s\\t\end{bmatrix}$ which in comparison if the question asked to compute $A^{-1}$ it would be $[A|I]$

Comment: Yes, but $[s,t]^{\top}$ multiplied on the right side of the identity matrix.

Comment: Ok thanks for explaining

Comment: No problem, hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just summarizing the comments discussion:

Notice that in Method 1, you have:
$\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\6&2\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}s\\t\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}s\\t\end{bmatrix}$.

This is equivalent to the augmented system you have implicitly:
$\begin{bmatrix}2&1 & (x) &| & 1 & 0 & (s) \\6&2& (y) & | & 0 & 1 & (t) \end{bmatrix}$.

By conducting the elementary row operations, it works on all rows and you obtain your result, hope it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Every elementary row operation has the effect of multiplying the matrix by an elementary matrix $E_i$. Since the total effect of row reduction is to reduce the matrix to the identity matrix, that means that all told you've multiplied the matrix by its inverse. Since you're doing the same thing to the vector (that forms the last column in the augmented matrix), you're also multiplying it by the inverse of the matrix.